# Visual Studio C# project dependency on C++ project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, dependencies, devops, project

I have a solution with C# and C++ projects. When I tried to add a dependency from C# library project to C++ console exe project, Visual Studio 2019 is not allowing it. I am trying it using References->Add Reference->Projects popup.

Then I was able to add dependency using solution properties using Project dependencies option. I do see C++ project getting built when C# project build is invoked. But the C++ project output binaries are not getting copied to C# project output folder.

Wondering what the trick is to get this working...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the console app to use the library but you are trying to create a dependency in the library project on the console app project. That is backwards. Libraries can't depend on applications. If the console app needs to use the library, add a dependency in the console app project to the library project.

Is your C++ project configured to be a managed code project or to use managed code libraries? If the C++ project is native C++, it can't use the C# library and you won't be able to add a project reference to the library project.

In the solution properties you can configure that the console app depends on the library. This will ensure that the library project will be built before the console project. The build dependencies in the solution properties are used to help determine the build order. Unlike with references in projects, solution build dependencies don't copy files.

Comment: This is a scenario where the C# lib project launches the native exe. I ended up adding dependency at solution level from C# to C++ project. But the C++ artifacts aren't getting copied to C# project output dir.

Comment: That's correct: solution build dependencies don't copy files. References in the project handle compile-time dependencies. I would inject a custom target that copies the run-time dependency that is the exe.

Comment: I found interesting results. I added a copy command in AfterBuild target of ProjectA, a C# project to pull outputs of native project ProjectB. I saw ProjectB binaries show up in ProjectA output dir. I have ProjectC, a C# project that depends on ProjectA. When I built ProjectC, I see both ProjectA and ProjectB getting built. But msbuild copied just the C# binary artifacts of ProjectA to ProjectC's output dir. It didn't copy the native exe that is available in ProjectA's output dir. I had to move the native artifact copy command to top level project.